# BigQuery: Computing the timestamp diff in time ordered rows in a group

Tags: google-bigquery

Given a table like this, I would like to compute the time duration of each state before changing to a different state:

```
id state timestamp
1  1     2018-08-17 10:40:00
1  2     2018-08-17 12:40:00
1  1     2018-08-17 14:40:00
2  1     2018-08-17 09:00:00
2  2     2018-08-17 12:00:00
```

The output I want is:

```
id state date       duration
1  1     2018-08-17 2 hours
1  2     2018-08-17 2 hours
1  1     2018-08-17 9 hours 20 minutes (until the end of the day in this case)
2  1     2018-08-17 3 hours
2  2     2018-08-17 12 hours (until the end of the day in this case)
```

I am not so sure whether this is doable in SQL. I feel like I have to write a UDF against aggregated state and timestamp (grouped by id and ordered by ts) which outputs an array of struct (id, state, date, and duration). This array can be flattened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, state, 
  IFNULL(
    TIMESTAMP_DIFF(LEAD(ts) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ts), ts, MINUTE), 
    24*60 - TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ts, TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(ts, DAY), MINUTE)
  ) AS duration_minutes
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data from  your question:

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 1 state, TIMESTAMP('2018-08-17 10:40:00') ts UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 2, '2018-08-17 12:40:00' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 1, '2018-08-17 14:40:00' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 1, '2018-08-17 09:00:00' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 2, '2018-08-17 12:00:00' 
)
SELECT id, state, 
  IFNULL(
    TIMESTAMP_DIFF(LEAD(ts) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ts), ts, MINUTE), 
    24*60 - TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ts, TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(ts, DAY), MINUTE)
  ) AS duration_minutes
FROM `project.dataset.table`
-- ORDER BY id, ts
```

with result as below

```
Row id  state   duration_minutes     
1   1   1        120     
2   1   2        120     
3   1   1        560     
4   2   1        180     
5   2   2        720
```

If you need your output formatted exactly the qay you showed in question - use below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, state, ts, duration_minutes,
  FORMAT('%i hours %i minutes', DIV(duration_minutes, 60), MOD(duration_minutes, 60)) duration
FROM (
  SELECT id, state, ts,
    IFNULL(
      TIMESTAMP_DIFF(LEAD(ts) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ts), ts, MINUTE), 
      24*60 - TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ts, TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(ts, DAY), MINUTE)
    ) AS duration_minutes
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
```

In this case you output will look like below

```
Row id  state   ts                        duration_minutes  duration     
1   1   1       2018-08-17 10:40:00 UTC   120               2 hours 0 minutes    
2   1   2       2018-08-17 12:40:00 UTC   120               2 hours 0 minutes    
3   1   1       2018-08-17 14:40:00 UTC   560               9 hours 20 minutes   
4   2   1       2018-08-17 09:00:00 UTC   180               3 hours 0 minutes    
5   2   2       2018-08-17 12:00:00 UTC   720               12 hours 0 minutes
```

Sure,  you will most likely still need to adjust above to your particular case  - but you've got a good start I think